# Subtract one Polygon from another

Tags: java, geometry, subtraction, jts

I have two Geometries (`org.locationtech.jts.geom`), in particular two Polygons. Now I want to subtract the intersection of both (the area they both share) from one of the Polygons so they do not share any area anymore. I know how to get the intersecting Geometry (`polygon1.intersection(polygon2)`), which is (in my case) always a Polygon.

My question is: **How can I subtract one Polygon from another, so they don't share any area anymore?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with a library, so maybe it can be done better. Subtracting a polygon is an intersecting with its complement. Assuming that your polygon doesn't have holes, you can use this constructor to construct a complement: http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/1.1.1/apidocs/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html#Polygon-org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing-org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing:A-org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory- . `shell` is the large enough bounding box. `holes` contain a `shell` of your initial polygon.

Comment: Forget what I said. There is a method `difference` which does the job: http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/1.1.1/apidocs/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#difference-org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry-

Comment: Thank you @dyukha! I had used `difference` but did it the wrong way.
With `geometry = polygon1.difference(polygon2)`, I get the geometry of polygon1 minus the one of polygon2, which is what I was looking for.